# How to modify the space between the numbers and text of sectioning titles in the table of contents?

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

I'm preparing a document using the `book` class. In the table of contents, the space between the subsection number and title is too wide. How to reduce it?

Comment: Some feedback would be really nice.

Answer (score 99):

**Without any packages:**

In the standard documentclass without the influence of a package like `titletoc` you have to redefine the command `\l@subsection`. In the file `book.cls` you find the following settings:

```
\newcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\newcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{3.8em}{3.2em}}
\newcommand*\l@subsubsection{\@dottedtocline{3}{7.0em}{4.1em}}
\newcommand*\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{4}{10em}{5em}}
\newcommand*\l@subparagraph{\@dottedtocline{5}{12em}{6em}}
```

The command `\@dottedtocline` expects the following parameters:

```
\renewcommand{\l@<typ>}{\@dottedtocline{<level>}%
                                       {<indentation>}%
                                       {<numwidth>}}
```

To reduce the indentation of `subsection` you can do:

```
\makeatletter
 \renewcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{1.8em}{3.2em}}
\makeatother
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{1.8em}{3.2 em}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{foo}
\section{bar}
\subsection{foobar}
\end{document}
```

The method is equal for floating environments. The standard class `book.cls` provides `\l@figure` and and `\l@table` with the following settings:

```
\newcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\let\l@table\l@figure
```

---

**Package [titletoc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc)**

By using the package [titletoc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) you can set the indentation using `\dottedcontents`:

```
\dottedcontents{<section>}[<left>]{<above-code>}
{<label width>}{<leader width>}
```

Example

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\dottedcontents{subsection}[5.5em]{}{3.2em}{1pc}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{foo}
\section{bar}
\subsection{foobar}
\end{document}
```

The argument `<section>` can be somewhat irritating. The argument allows the name without a leading backslash so that `figure` and `table` are allowed, too.

---

**Package [tocloft](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft)**

The package [tocloft](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) offers more than the following setting. The indentation is set by the length `\cftXindent`. The `X` stands for:

- part for `\part` titles
- chap for `\chapter` titles
- sec for `\section` titles
- subsec for `\subsection` titles
- subsubsec for `\subsubsection` titles
- para for `\paragraph` titles
- fig for `figure \caption` title
- tab for `table \caption` titles

Example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{2em}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{foo}
\section{bar}
\subsection{foobar}
\end{document}
```

---

**[KOMA-Script](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script)**

With a recent version of KOMA-Script one can use `\RedeclareSectionCommand` to change the entries in the table of contents as well. You can use that for all defined sectioning commands.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
tocindent=9em,tocnumwidth=7em,]{subsection}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{foo}
\section{bar}
\subsection{foobar}
\end{document}
```

The modification of `figure` and `table` is equal to the standard class and defined as follow:

```
\newcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\let\l@table\l@figure
```

---

**Package [tocstyle](http://www.komascript.de/komascriptbestandteile)** (link in German)

*With recent versions of KOMA-Scrpt, many parts of `tocstyle` are unneeded. It will be completely incorporated in KOMA-Script in the future.*

To manipulate the toc (or other list of ...) in combination with a class of the [KOMA](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) bundle you should use the package `tocstyle`. The package is part of the [KOMA](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) bundle but with a [separate documentation](http://www.komascript.de/komascriptbestandteile). The influence of the indentation is given indirectly by `entryhook` which can be set by  `\settocfeature`

One of the benefits of`tocstyle` is the automatic calculation of the needed indentation.

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{KOMAlike}
\settocfeature[toc][2]{entryhook}{\protect\hspace*{-1.5em}\nobreakspace}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{foo}
\section{bar}
\subsection{foobar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: tocstyle without option `tocindentmanual` calculates the needed indention itself, so to much indent shouldn't be. And the depth of subsection is AFAIK 2, so the second optional argument of `\settocfeature` should be 2 not 9. BTW: If the space after the number is to large you may change the feature `spaceafternumber`.

Comment: @Schweinebacke: Welcome on stack exchange. I toke the wrong number ;-). Thanks. The `spaceafternumber` influence the space between the number and the title. I want to reduce the intention in front of the section number.

Comment: If added the information about `spaceafternumber` only, because I'm not sure if the OP wanted to change the indentation before the number or the indentation of the text, because there's a hanging indent after the number. It shouldn't be a critic to your excellent answer only an addendum.

Comment: @Schweinebacke: I doesn't sound like critic ;-). But adding this information to my answer I must change also the other sections. (regards mechanicus -- mrunix :-) )

Comment: OK. BTW: `<distance "number <-> text" >` sounds like space between number and text, but its the hanging indent of the text aka the width reserved for number and space between number and text.

Comment: @Schweinebacke: What do you suggest? I searched a short description of this behavior.

Comment: With my about 25 year unused school english it's hard to find a good term. Maybe "width of number". At source2e the LaTeX team simply uses `\@dottedtocline{` _⟨level⟩_ `}{` _⟨indent⟩_ `}{` _⟨numwidth⟩_ `}{` _⟨title⟩_ `}{` _⟨page⟩_ `}`.

Comment: @Schweinebacke: I know the problem with "school English".

Comment: I need to reduce space BEFORE number and title of subsection in the tableofcontents

Comment: @IlyaGinzburg: Do you use any additional packages or which documentclass do you use? indention isn't the same as space above or below.

Comment: Since KOMA-Script version 3.16 you can use `\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocindent=1.8em,tocnumwidth=3.2em]{subsection}`.

Comment: This was such a great and inclusive answer.  Thank you so much. (Special props for KOMA.)

Comment: The first solution also works in LyX with `titlesec`

Comment: I wanted to change the spacing for chapters too, and that setting (for `\l@chapter`) can be found in `book.cls` as well.

Comment: The note about KOMA-Script's `figure` and `table` is not correct (anymore). `\l@figure` and `\l@table` are defined using `tocbasic`'s `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry` and should be modified using `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry`. This also works with a standard class ([see my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/702375/277964)).

Comment: The experimental `tocstyle` is no longer part of KOMA-Script nor of MiKTeX or TeX Live. However the automatic calculation can be done using `tocbasic` as shown in [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/702375/277964).

Answer (score 6):

The macro in charge of setting the numbers and space between the titles is `\numberline`. It's defined in the [LaTeX kernel](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co) as:

```
\def\numberline#1{\hb@xt@\@tempdima{#1\hfil}}
```

`\numberline{<stuff>}` sets its argument `<stuff>` inside a box of width `\@tempdima`. The length `\@tempdima` is set by the macros `\l@<type>` that is responsible for setting any `<type>` within the ToC (like `section`, `subsection`, `figure`, etc.).

If you wish to have a *natural* separation between the numbers and titles within the ToC, you need to modify `\numberline` to not set its contents in a box, but rather just set the number followed by some space, as in:

```
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{#1~}
```

The above redefinition will set the number followed by a `~` (tie). You can change this to suit your needs (`\hspace{<len>}`, `:~`, ...). Note that this will hold for for all elements that use it (including `figure`s in the LoF and `table`s in the LoT).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{#1~}

\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example
\AtBeginDocument{\sloppy}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{A section}
\lipsum[1-50]

\setcounter{section}{9}
\section{Another section}
\lipsum[1-50]

\setcounter{section}{99}
\section{Yet another section}
\lipsum[1-50]

\setcounter{section}{999}
\section{Last section}
\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

If you're using [`tocloft`](//ctan.org/pkg/tocloft), a similar setup applies with some minor alterations, since `tocloft` allows for the insertion of content `b`efore and `a`fter the `s`ectional unit `num`bering:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{{\@cftbsnum #1\@cftasnum~}\@cftasnumb}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [package `tocbasic`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocbasic) and reconfigure the ToC entries, to automatically detect the needed space for the numbers and the hierarchical indent:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[dynnumwidth,dynindent]{tocline}{section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}% Reconfigure ToC entries for section … subparagraph to use the needed number width and indent

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\blinddocument

\setcounter{section}{9}
\blinddocument

\setcounter{section}{99}
\blinddocument

\setcounter{section}{999}
\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

After two LaTeX runs the problem is still there:

[image: ToC with problem]

But after at least three LaTeX runs you get:

[image: After three LaTeX runs everything is fine.]

If you work with a KOMA-Script class or a derived class instead of a standard class, you don't need to load `tocbasic` yourself, because the KOMA-Script classes already use this package. On the other hand, as you see in the example above, you don't need to use a KOMA-Script class to be able to use the features of `tocbasic`.