# Spacing between number and title in List of Tables

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to modify the indentation before sectioning titles in the table of contents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33841/how-to-modify-the-indentation-before-sectioning-titles-in-the-table-of-contents)

I need to add some space between the number of the table and the title of the table since they overlap in the list of tables.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.