# Not enough space between figure number and figure caption in list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to modify the indentation before sectioning titles in the table of contents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33841/how-to-modify-the-indentation-before-sectioning-titles-in-the-table-of-contents)

LaTex experts, 
I am using latex for my thesis writing. I found an annoying problem which is in the list of figure (same problem in the list of tables), there is no enough hspace between the figure number and the figure description. My list of figures looks like this.

```
1.1 hello

1.2 help

1.3 ...

1.10Problem
```

Please note that there is no space between 1.10 and problem.

Could anyone please help?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33841/how-to-modify-the-indentation-before-sectioning-titles-in-the-table-of-contents/33842#33842

Comment: `\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{<len>}}` where you specify `<len>` (it's given as `2.3em` in the standard classes, so you would be interested in something greater than that (perhaps `3em`).