# Problem using {tocloft} to fix list of figures spacing error in LyX

Tags: lyx, tocloft

I've been having issues with my figure numbers running into my figure titles in LyX. I searched and found that inserting:

```
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\cftsetindents{figure}{0em}{3.5em}
\cftsetindents{table}{0em}{3.5em}
```

into the preamble helps to fix that issue and it did!

But that creates a new issue for me:  Now at the top of each section, 
there is now a random "Chapter ." label that shows up.

At the start of the Table of Content, List of Figures, List of Tables, and Dedication, etc.

And then with each Chapter in addition to the actual Chapter heading that's been there previously, "Chapter 1" "Chapter 2" etc. show up at the head of each Chapter.

Any help with getting rid of these extra chapter headings and still retaining the list of figures spacing would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I would rather add some space to the `\cftfignumwidth` length instead of changing the indent!

Comment: Thanks @HeikoOberdiek. I've been trying to get a hold of an MWE. i used a layout template provided by someone who has since graduated, so I'm still trying to figure out how to open that .layout document file. Also thanks Christian for the space suggestion. I tried that as well but I still get the weird chapter labeling. I think there's something with the {tocloft} package itself that's not agreeing with my formatting.

Comment: I've added the code to my original question.  (not sure if it qualifies as the MWE) as I couldn't find the same \documentclass ... but just the LaTexClass @HeikoOberdiek

Answer (score 0):

not sure what exactly the issue was, but I ultimately found this to help: [list of figures disappears if I use tocloft package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67167/list-of-figures-disappears-if-i-use-tocloft-package?rq=1)
in short using this instead of the package:

```
\makeatletter    
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{4em}}    
\makeatother
```