# List of figures: numbers overlap image caption

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

I have many images in a part of my document, now the list of figures numbers collide with its respective image caption as seen below. There would be enough space to move the text a bit more to the right... is there any way to reconfigure the LOF?

[image: LOF]

Comment: very like the question [How to modify the indentation before sectioning titles in the table of contents?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33841/)

Comment: In the answer to the question linked by barbara also this case is covered, look for `\l@figure` and apply to it the same method suggested for the other cases.

Comment: Thank you, @barbarabeeton and egreg. I already found the linked question by searching myself, but didn't know wheter it applied to my problem or how to test it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From the linked question in the comments, I figured out the following:

```
\makeatletter
     \renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1em}{3.2em}}
\makeatother
```

Which produces:

[image: LOF]