# Problem listing more than 100 images in index

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I have an appendix for a thesis with more than 100 images. The problem I have is that the generated index for those images *glues* the numbers with the caption.

Here is an image of what is happening:
[image: problem_image]

However, for images below 100, everything seems to be fine:
[image: wanted_result]

I am using a template from my university, which I present here:

- https://github.com/joaomlourenco/unlthesis/tree/master/LaTeX

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: @cmhughes index means table of contents  and similar lists at the front in some languages and the thing we call an index at the back  is called something else:-)

Comment: the list of figures uses something like (from `article`) `\newcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}`  so you can renew that command with bigger lengths to make more room

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ah, indeed, thanks for the clarification - have deleted my comment :)

Comment: perhaps [Adjusting spaces for the ToC](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39971) and the links within will provide a starting point. In fact, [List of figures: numbers overlap image caption](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87019) looks like a duplicate ....

Comment: @cmhughes thanks I knew it had to be a duplicate of something

Comment: @ChristianHupfer no it's the width of the numbers.

Comment: Will check that duplicate thing !

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, it it the with of the box holding `A.XX`, it has a fixed size and here it is just too small.

Comment: The solution in the recommended discussion fixed the problem, thanks !