# Extended titles for subsections gets my TOC all pilled-up

Tags: table-of-contents

Some of the sections and subsections of my work has extended titles, i.e.: `\section{bla bla bla ....... bla}`, so when pdflatex creates my `.pdf`, the toc gets all pilled-up, as show in picture.

[image: pilled-up toc]

How can I prevent this?

Comment: You could use the `titletoc/titlesec` package  to easily customise the appearance of your table of contents. It's a matter of re-defining another width for the labels.

Comment: There are a number of posts that deal with this: [Numbers too close to figure captions in List of Figures, can this be fixed without changing the class?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117088/5764); [List of figures: numbers overlap image caption](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87019/5764); [Adjusting spaces for the ToC](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39971/5764). Perhaps the best (canonical) answer would be to look at [How to modify the indentation before sectioning titles in the table of contents?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33841/5764).

Comment: ...with [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) adjust `\cftsecnumwidth` to something like 2.5em. or `\cftsecindent` to (say) 2em...

Comment: Or you could use shorter titles for the TOC using the optional argument e.g. `\section[Short title]{Long title}`.

Comment: thx Werner! The canonical answer did the trick. http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33841/5764