# What the first argument for `\l@subsection` actually is?

Tags: sectioning, latex-base

Consider for example the code

```
  \makeatletter 
     \renewcommand{\l@subsection}[2]{\@dottedtocline{2}{1.6em}{1.6em}{\S#1}{#2}}
  \makeatother
```

It allows me to obtain in my table of contents records with paragraph (section) sign before the number of subsection. But I want also to have a point after the number of subsection without modification of `\thesubsection` command.

Looking at second and third arguments for `\@dottedtocline` I think that first argument for `\l@subsection` is actually something that behaves like encapsulated pair of number of subsection and of title of subsection (because we can control the distance between these two elements of argument #1 by third argument of `\@dottedtocline`).

My question is what actually the first argument to `\l@subsection` is and if it is possible to get from this argument the number of subsection and its title as separated values?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: See also [`tocloft`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tocloft)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to modify the indentation before sectioning titles in the table of contents?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33841/how-to-modify-the-indentation-before-sectioning-titles-in-the-table-of-contents)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the LaTeX kernel, `\@dottedtocline` is implemented with the following syntax:

```
\@dottedtocline{<level>}{<indent>}{<numwidth>}{<title>}{<page>}
```

- `<level>` is an integer number that controls if the entry is typeset; if `<level>` is greater than `\c@tocdepth` (the internal form of the `tocdepth` counter), then no line will be produced.
- `<indent>` is the total indentation from the left margin.
- `<numwidth>` is the width of box for number if the `<title>` has a `\numberline` command.
- `<title>` is the actual contents of entry.
- `<page>` is the page number.

The second argument for `\l@subsection` corresponds to the page; the first argument, to the number (if any) *and* the text.

To get the desires result, one easy possibility would be to use the `tocloft` package which offers appropriate hooks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand\cftsubsecaftersnum{.}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecpresnum{\S}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{Test Section}
\subsection{Test Subsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, then I think that I can use `\patchcmd` to make a point after `\numberline{...}`. But is it possible to obtain somehow such number within `\numberline` parameter from <title>? In other words, can I split <title> into number (under assumption that it always starts with \numberline) and the other text?

Comment: @Nimza I would suggest you to use the `tocloft` package to make the change.

Comment: @Nimza I added such an example to my answer.

Comment: Great thanks for this answer! I like this `tocloft`! Do you know if `tocloft` is compatible with `titlesec`? I.e can I define my own titleclass (instead of section, subsection, e.t.c.) with `titlesec` and customise its toc entries with `tocloft`?

Comment: @Nimza yes, it can be done; you define your new sectional units using `titlesec` and then you can use `\newlistentry` (from `titletoc`) to make `titletoc` aware of the new sectional units; this wll allow you to use the whole family of `\cft...` commands for the new units. The only precaution is not to duplicate the definition of counters (each call to `\newlistentry` creates an associated counter).

Answer (score 6):

To get the result you are asking for you can redefine `\numberline` locally in a group around the subsection line.  You will also need to increase the space for the label.  Doing it this way, you can also move the `\S` command into the `\numberline` command:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter 
\def\dottednumberline#1{\hb@xt@\@tempdima{\S#1.\hfil}}
\renewcommand{\l@subsection}[2]{{\let\numberline\dottednumberline\@dottedtocline{2}{1.6em}{2.6em}{#1}{#2}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Test section}

\subsection{Test subsection}

\section{Another section}

\subsection{Another subsection}
\end{document}
```

This works since in the `.toc` we have

```
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.1}Test subsection}{1}
```

and `\l@subsection` will be applied to the second and third arguments, i.e.

```
#1 = \numberline {1.1}Test subsection
#2 = 1
```

the latter being the page number.  You can see these arguments directly by adding `\tracingmacros=1` to your document and examining the `.log` file.