# Ajdust width for the number of section

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, numbering

I have a problem with table of contents. I have changed the numbers of sections, that instead of numbers I have words, lets say "Dodatok A". But now, when the "number" of section is longer, the title of section and the "Dodatok A" are crossing, so it is not readable. Is there any way how to adjust the width of box for the number of section? I put here a picture with a part of table of contents, where you can see the problem. Thank you.

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 
    \usepackage[slovak]{babel} 
    \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} 
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
    \usepackage{palatino,verbatim}  
    \usepackage{graphicx} 
    \usepackage{multirow}  
    \usepackage{amsmath} 
    \usepackage{pstricks}
    \usepackage{wrapfig} 
    \usepackage{epsfig} 
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
   \usepackage{color} 
   \linespread{1.3} 
   \usepackage[total={17cm,25cm}, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=3.5cm, right=2cm, includefoot]{geometry}  
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{calc,etoolbox}
\usepackage[titletoc,toc,title]{appendix}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

     \begin{document} 
     \tableofcontents 

    some sections, subsections, figures etc.

    \setcounter{section}{0}
      \setcounter{subsection}{0}
      \renewcommand\thesection{Dodatok \Alph{section}}

     \setcounter{figure}{0}
      \setcounter{equation}{0}
      \renewcommand\thefigure{\Alph{section}\arabic{figure}}
      \renewcommand\theequation{\Alph{section}\arabic{equation}}

    \section{Kalibračná symetria pre elektromagnetizmus}
    text text 

     \end{document}
```

[image: A picture of a part of my table of contents, where you can see my problem.]

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: I would agree. Your answer should be adjusted though to incorporate some difference when using a class like `article` compared to `book` and/or `report`. [`article.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls) defines `\l@section` differently to that of [`book.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/book.cls) and [`report.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls) and therefore requires different treatment.

Comment: Suzie, you can drop the use of [`epsfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/epsfig) as it is deprecated.

Comment: @Werner: But only if you don't use any related package.

Answer (score 2):

This sort of adjustment is usually left for packages like [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft). However, a manual adjustment is also possible by inserting content for the adjustment into the ToC at the right time. The use of [`babel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/babel) does make things a tad trickier, since `babel` defines certain language-specific shorthands. These shorthands influence the capability to patch (or modify) commands on the fly. In particular, [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) is used to patch `\l@section` - the macro responsible for setting `section`-style entries in the ToC - while temporarily turning off the shorthand for `-`; set active by `babel`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc,etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{calc,etoolbox}
\usepackage[slovak]{babel}% http://ctan.org/pkg/babel
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{A section}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{Section~\Alph{section}}
\makeatletter
\addtocontents{toc}{%
  \protect\shorthandoff{-}% Remove 'active'ness of '-'
  \protect\patchcmd{\protect\l@section}{1.5em}{\widthof{\textbf{Section X\quad}}}{}{}%
  \protect\shorthandon{-}}% Make '-' active again
\makeatother

\section{Another section}

\end{document}
```

Since `\tableofcontents` reads content from the `.toc` file, it's appearance is usually delayed by at least one compilation. To that end, and somewhat counter-intuitive for those unfamiliar with TeX's auxiliary file usage, you need to insert the ToC-related adjustment within your document. The above does this, by inserting a patch to replace to default `1.5em` space allowed for the section number with `\widthof{\textbf{Section X\quad}}` - the new width of section "numbers."

Comment: Thank you very much. I must be doing something wrong, but it doesn't work. I made this changes in my code: 1. add `\usepackage{calc,etoolbox}` to the preamble, 2. add `\makeatletter
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\patchcmd{\protect\l@section}{1.5em}{\widthof{\textbf{Section X\quad}}}{}{}}
\makeatother` above the `\section{Kalibračná symetria pre elektromagnetizmus}` . Is it good?

Comment: @Suzie: Yes, that looks good (just like I did in my MWE). You mention that "it doesn't work". What exactly? Does a compilation produce an error? Is there no change? When you look at `<filename>.toc` in your working folder, is there anything in there that resembles `\patchcmd` like inserted above? Are you using any ToC-related packages (I tested it even with [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) and there's no problem).

Comment: `@Werner` No error, but no changes. I am using only those packages, that are included in my code (I have edited it so now there are all). In the `.toc file`, there is  this: `\patchcmd {\l@section }{1.5em}{\widthof {\textbf {Section X\hskip 1em\relax }}}{}{}`.

Comment: @Suzie: This must mean that the patch is not working. Change the last two empty arguments `{}{}` in the `\patchcmd` to `{\protect\typeout{success}}{\protect\typeout{failure}}`. This should output `success` in your `.log` if the patch was successful and `failure` otherwise. I see `success` when I review the `.log` file. What do you see?

Comment: ...moreover, what about using some of the suggestions within [How to modify the indentation before sectioning titles in the table of contents?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33841/5764) to correct the behaviour? Mine does a direct/manual adjustment. However, you could also use other packages, if this doesn't work for you.

Comment: I see failure....

Comment: @Suzie: If you see `failure`, then the patch was not successful. I see now that it has to do with your inclusion of `babel`. I'll work on it...

Comment: @Suzie: I've updated my answer to consider [`babel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/babel). The problem was that the patch can only occur when `babel`'s shorthand usage has been temporarily disabled.