# Table of Contents overlapping type

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm creating a report that uses roman numeral section numbers (requirement for the conference that I'm submitting to). When I create the table of contents, I'm having the following problem:
[image]

With the section numbers overlapping the section names. Is there a simple fix for this, perhaps by adding more spacing between the number and name for every section? I'm no expert with style files, but with some instruction I could find what I need and change it.

Comment: See [How to modify the indentation before sectioning titles in the table of contents?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33841/5764)