# TOC edit the numbering from the part section in the TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, parts

I am very new to Tex, I am working of a template that someone else has given me.

I am try to change the  **/part{Part I: my stuff}** from looking like this in the TOC

```
 1 Introduction

 I  Part I: my stuff

 2  Procedure blah blah

 3  Procedure blah blah

 II Part II: my stuff

 4  Procedure blah blah
```

to something like:

```
 1 Introduction

 Part I: my stuff

    2  Procedure blah blah

    3  Procedure blah blah

 Part II: my stuff

    4  Procedure blah blah
```

Currently I have this

```
%% ---------------------------------------------------------------------- %%
\mainmatter

% Main matter
% -> Global Introduction
\input{Chapters/Introduction.tex} 
%% *****     PART 1     *****
\part*{<Insert Title of First Part>}

\input{Chapters/SummaryPartA.tex}

%% *****     PART 2     *****
\part*{<Insert Title of second Part>}

\input{Chapters/SummaryPartB.tex}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: This partly depends on which documentclass you are using.  Can you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Also, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33841/15925 looks very similar to your question.

Comment: Thanks Andrew its actually a custom Thesis class which is based on the book.cls

Comment: The question I linked to is specifically about the `book.cls`.  Does it solve your problem?  If not you will need to provide a link to your custom class.

Comment: It helps with the indentation problem, just missing the step to re-edit the part numbering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works with the `book` document class, so I hope it will work with yours, too, since it is based on this one.

It seems to me that you want the indenting for `\chapter`s starting with the second one. So we can add a line (requires the `tocloft` package)

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setlength{\cftchapindent}{2em}}
```

just after the first `\chapter`.

Also, to have no numbers in the ToC for numbered `\part`s, we can patch the command `\@part` through `\patchcmd` in this way (requires the `etoolbox` package)

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@part}
    {\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}}
    {\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}}
    {}
    {}
\makeatother
```

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@part}
    {\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}}
    {\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}}
    {}
    {}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setlength{\cftchapindent}{2em}}
\part{Part I: my stuff}
\chapter{Procedure blah blah}
\chapter{Procedure blah blah}
\part{Part II: my stuff}
\chapter{Procedure blah blah}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Karl, Oh Ah. Check didn't appear in my browser. I will delete it.