# formatting of the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

How can I change the settings of my table of contents, so that the sections and subsections are not indented as shown in the second picture. I would also like to center the title of the Contents. I am using the `article` class.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide us with some code in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)? ToCs are dependent on the packages that you're using to create sectional units, and also the type of `\documentclass` you're using.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is an approach which uses the »[tocstyle](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocstyle)« package with the `tocflat` option along with the `standard` style.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[tocflat]{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{standard}

\usepackage{blindtext}

% Redefinition of ToC command to get centered heading
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
  \null\hfill\textbf{\Large\contentsname}\hfill\null\par
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}%
  \@starttoc{toc}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

  \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

You can compare with the `tocfullflat` option for equidistant spaces between numbers and heading entries. More details can be found in the package manual.

**N.B.:** You will get a warning about the alpha status of the package. So far is has not caused any major problems for me.

---

[image]

Answer (score 18):

Using the [`tocloft`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) package, all you have to do is to set the indents to the same values: `0em` (so entries are flushed to the left margin) and `2em` (space to typeset the unit number). Using `\cfttoctitlefont` and `\cftaftertoctitle` you can center the title; I also set `tocdepth` to `2` since subsubsections are not to be listed according to the image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\cftsetindents{section}{0em}{2em}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{0em}{2em}

\renewcommand\cfttoctitlefont{\hfill\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftaftertoctitle{\hfill\mbox{}}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\section*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
\section{Test section one}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection}
\subsection{Test subsection}

\section{Test section two}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection}
\subsection{Test subsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Here's a solution using [`titletoc`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) package; it defines the `dottedcontents` command which has syntax:

```
% \dottedcontents{<section>}[<left>]{<above-code>}
% {<label width>}{<leader width>}
```

I have also used the command

```
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\centering Contents}
```

to center the table of contents title.

[image: screenshot]

Here's the code:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titletoc}

% \dottedcontents{<section>}[<left>]{<above-code>}
% {<label width>}{<leader width>}
\dottedcontents{section}[0em]{\bfseries}{2.9em}{1pc}
\dottedcontents{subsection}[0em]{}{3.3em}{1pc}

% center the toc heading
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\centering Contents}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
\section{Test section one}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\subsection{Test subsection}

\section{Test section two}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\subsection{Test subsection}

\end{document}
```

For further reading, see [How to modify the space between the numbers and text of sectioning titles in the table of contents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33841/how-to-modify-the-indentation-before-sectioning-titles-in-the-table-of-contents).