# How to underline the heading of List of Acronyms?

Tags: sectioning, acronyms, underline, acro

Following is my **MWE** of my thesis, using to create a **LIST OF ACRONYMS**.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}


\acsetup{
  index = false,
  list-long-format = \makefirstuc ,
  list-name={LIST OF ACRONYMS},
  list-style = lof , %because I want the list to be similar as LOF
  list-heading = lof,
  extra-style = comma, 
  list-short-width =6em
}

\DeclareAcronym{DBSCAN}{
  short = DBSCAN ,
  long = Density-Based Spatial Clustering of Applications with Noise ,
  short-plural ={s} ,
  long-plural = {s},
  class = general ,
  short-format = \scshape ,
  index = DBSCAN
}

\begin{document}

\ac{DBSCAN}

\printacronyms[sort=true]

\end{document}
```

I am getting the following output

[image]

What I want is, to underline the heading of **LIST OF ACRONYMS** just like the following

[image]

Moreover, how could I get the same font as **LIST OF FIGURES**. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Below is the code, I believe, would have been used to generate LOF including some of the other code in the preamble.

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]   
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}   
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{30pt}

\setlength\cftbeforechapskip{10pt}
\renewcommand\cftfigafterpnum{\vskip8pt\par}
\renewcommand\cfttabafterpnum{\vskip8pt\par}
\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\vskip8pt}
\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vskip8pt}

\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\chapter}{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{15\p@}}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\section}{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{15\p@}}}{}{}
\makeatother


\makeatletter
\def\BState{\State\hskip-\ALG@thistlm}
\newenvironment{figurehere}{\def\@captype{figure}}{}
\makeatother

\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\textbf\normalfont}
\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{{\normalfont}}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\contentsname{TABLE OF CONTENTS}}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\contentsname{\leftline{LIST OF FIGURES}}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\bfseries\Large}
{\vspace{0.005cm}\centering \Large\bfseries{Chapter \thechapter}}
{1ex}
{\bfseries\Large\centering}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\textbf{\textit{Annex M1}}}
\lhead{}
\rfoot{ \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[OR]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[EL]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
}
\tableofcontents
\include{tables}
\include{figures}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Acronyms}
\setlength\cftparskip{-2pt}
\setlength\cftbeforechapskip{0pt}
\printacronyms[sort=true]
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please also include the code used to generate the lof-heading?

Comment: @Skillmon Thank you for your response, I am editing my question to post the code. Please take a look.

Comment: Your first MWE uses `article`, your second code block sets the style of the `\chapter` headings. Which class are you actually using?

Comment: I asked two questions here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521956/space-between-acronym-and-its-description-when-using-lof-style-for-list-of-acron/521960?noredirect=1#comment1320007_521960 . I got answered to one. I asked the 2nd one here. My apologies if I was not able to clearly mention the question. This post includes my whole preamble and the class I am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To influence the appearance of the heading, such as adding a line, you can use the `\DeclareAcroListHeading` macro from the `acro` package as described on page 39 of the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/acro/acro_en.pdf). In the MWE below a line is added that fills the text space, i.e., the same width and position as the text. A negative space of `1Em` is added to shift the line a bit up.

`\DeclareAcroListHeading` is intended to format the header text itself, and the text is autmoatically given as an argument for the macro that is defined. Here `\section*` is used for that, which is the default for list headings and results in the same appearance as the original list heading.

You can adjust the width and position of the line and/or the entries in the list of acronyms to make them match the appearance of the list of figures more closely, if required.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}

\newcommand{\sectionuline}[1]{%
\section*{#1}
\vspace{-1Em}
\noindent\hrulefill
}
\DeclareAcroListHeading{loa}{\sectionuline}

\acsetup{
  index = false,
  list-long-format = \makefirstuc ,
  list-name={LIST OF ACRONYMS},
  list-style = lof , %because I want the list to be similar as LOF
  list-heading = loa, % note that the new macro is used here
  extra-style = comma, 
  list-short-width =6em
}

\DeclareAcronym{DBSCAN}{
  short = DBSCAN ,
  long = Density-Based Spatial Clustering of Applications with Noise ,
  short-plural ={s} ,
  long-plural = {s},
  class = general ,
  short-format = \scshape ,
  index = DBSCAN
}

\begin{document}

\ac{DBSCAN}

\printacronyms[sort=true]

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Much appreciated.