# Adjusting lof style in acro 3.8 (list-short-width and list-caps options are gone)

Tags: acro

I am trying to compile on older document that was originally set up using acro 1.x. The document used the following settings:

```
\acsetup{
    first-long-format = \itshape,
    list-style = lof,
    list-short-width = 6.4em,
    list-caps = true,
    pages = first
}
```

On my current system I only have acro 3.8, which threw me a bunch of errors upon compilation. After going through the documentation I found the equivalents for some of the previous parameters:

```
\acsetup{
    format/first-long = \itshape,
    list/template = lof,
    pages/display = first
}
```

However it seems the following two options are gone:

1. **list-short-width** -  Sets the width of the acronym column in the list of abbreviations
2. **list-caps** - Makes the written out acronyms in the list of abbreviations start with a capital letter.

Unfortunately all of my attemps in searching for a solution to adjust the column width lead me to older questions, where the solution was using `list-short-width`. Based on the documentation I also played a bit around with setting `templates/colspec`, but I didn't manage to get a working solution so far...

Any idea on how can I restore the previous behavior using aro 3.8?

---

Minimal example:

```
% !TeX spellcheck = en_US
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}%
%
\usepackage{acro}%
%
\DeclareAcronym{ransac}{
    short=RANSAC,
    long=random sample consensus
}%
%
\DeclareAcronym{sift}{
    short=SIFT,
    long=scale invariant feature transform
}%
%
\acsetup{
    format/first-long = \itshape,
    list/template = lof,
    pages/display = first
    %list-caps = true,
    %list-short-width=6.4em,
}%
%
\begin{document}%
\section{Some Text}
\Ac{ransac} is a common approach to match features like \ac{sift}.

\section*{List of Abbreviations}
\printacronyms[heading=none]%

\end{document}%
```

Current output:

[image: Output]

Desired list appearance (original document):

[image: Output in old document]

Comment: I think you want `\acsetup{list/template=longtable}`, probably without any further modifications?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. With `\acsetup{list/template=longtable}`the first column is at least not reaching into the second one anymore, but there are a few other issues instead: 1) The overall table width doesn't match `\linewidth`, 2) the first column is formatted in bold and 3) the written out acronyms still don't start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: Yes, I thought there might be more.  I can probably sort that all out but I think I've dug up the necessary for `lof`, as far as `list-caps` you want sentence casing (so typically `\Acl`) rather than title casing right?

Comment: Regarding the first two points I already figured that I can fix them by setting `\acsetup{templates/colspec = p{0.15\linewidth}p{.819\linewidth}}` and adding `\setlength\LTleft{-0.45em}`. The values are from my original document template, so they might not match perfect for the minimal example. Unfortunately I'm failing with the uppercasing so far. The intended behavior is indeed only to have a capital first letter as in `\Acl`. However, adding something like `>{\expandafter\MakeUppercase}` to the second column doesn't work as Latex adds a `\noindent` at the beginning of the cell content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as capitalisation, the `list-caps` key seems to have an equivalent in `\acsetup{uppercase/list=true}` however this key is undocumented. `\acsetup{format/list=\acroupper}` is probably not an intended method but will also work as `\acroupper` is internally the difference between `\Ac` and `\ac`.

For the list there are a couple of options with differing dependencies.

- `lof` can be modified through use of [`tocloft`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) as described in [cgnieder's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/574863/106162) to [Space between acronym and its description when using LOF style for List of Acronyms](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/521956/106162). This matches the screenshot provided reasonably well, but deviates from the `lof` style that [`acro`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/acro) ships with.
- The table-based lists (`tabular`/`longtable`) also largely match the screenshot provided without modification.  These default to a bold short form, due to the default `templates/colspec=>{\bfseries}lp{.7\linewidth}`, which can be overriden with `\acsetup{templates/colspec=lp{.7\linewidth}}`.  We can span the full page width setting `\acsetup{templates/colspec=p{6em}p{\linewidth-6em-3\tabcolsep}}` (relying on [`calc`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/calc) for the in-place maths).
- `tabularray` may also be worth looking into as it allows the first column to be `l` (not requiring a hard-coded width) and the second will automatically fill, but the current (3.8) [`acro`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/acro) template is a bit awkward to customise without resorting to `\RenewAcroTemplate` (in the below I've left the columns as default and used a very hacky local setting of `format/short=\normalfont` to override the built-in `\bfseries`), I'm also not sure where the extra vertical space after the heading is coming from there.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}% for lof - needs to be loaded before acro
\usepackage{array}% for tabular/longtable list templates
\usepackage{longtable}% for longtable list template
\usepackage{tabularray}% for tabularray list template
\usepackage{calc}% for easy calculations within colspec
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{ransac}{
    short=RANSAC,
    long=random sample consensus
}
\DeclareAcronym{sift}{
    short=SIFT,
    long=scale invariant feature transform
}

\acsetup{
    format/first-long = \itshape,
    pages/display = first,
    format/list = \acroupper
}

\SetupAcroTemplate[list]{lof}{
  \setlength\cftfignumwidth{6em}
}

\acsetup{templates/colspec=p{6em}p{\linewidth-6em-3\tabcolsep}}

\begin{document}%
\section{Some Text}
\Ac{ransac} is a common approach to match features like \ac{sift}.

\printacronyms[template=lof]%
\printacronyms[template=tabular]%
{
\acsetup{format/short=\normalfont}
\printacronyms[template=tabularray]
}

\end{document}
```

[image: Compiled code showing the adapted lof, tabular, and tabularray lists]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works great - except for one special case which is nested acronyms like `\DeclareAcronym{rgb}{short=RGB, long={red, green, and blue}}  
\DeclareAcronym{rgbd}{short=RGB-D, long=\ac{rgb} and depth}`. I only have this one case, where both acronyms appear right behind each other in the list, so I just wrote plain "RBG" in the second one as no reader will ever look for a hyperlink there. Another solution would be renaming the reference from `rgb` to `RGB`. However, out of pure academic curiosity, I would be interested in knowing how to solve this properly...

Comment: Ah, that's interesting, amusing it gives a fairly acceptable failure path in your case. I've just realised the undocumented `uppercase/list` is probably intended to replace `short-caps`, but that flat out errors with nested acronyms.  Could you ask a separate question about nesting acronyms while capitalising the list? There are probably a couple of approaches and this Q&A is already a little broad, It can just use the default list and any answers should readily transfer.

Comment: I'm not sure if I actually have anything more intelligent to say than use `list=RGB and depth` but somebody else might have a better idea.