# Title overlaps with numbering in table of contents using tocbibind

Tags: tocbibind

The following document

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{bookman}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Lorem ipsum}
\chapter{Lorem ipsum}
\chapter{Lorem ipsum}
\chapter{Lorem ipsum}
\chapter{Lorem ipsum}
\chapter{Lorem ipsum}
\chapter{Lorem ipsum}
\chapter{Lorem ipsum}
\chapter{Lorem ipsum}
\chapter{Lorem ipsum}
\section{lorem ipsum}
\section{lorem ipsum}
\section{lorem ipsum}
\section{lorem ipsum}
\section{lorem ipsum}
\section{lorem ipsum}
\section{lorem ipsum}
\section{lorem ipsum}
\section{lorem ipsum}
\section{lorem ipsum}
\end{document}
```

produces the following pdf

[image: overlapping title and numbering]

How can I fix the overlap?

Comment: Please, look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33841/how-to-modify-the-space-between-the-numbers-and-text-of-sectioning-titles-in-the

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @Papiro thanks for the reference, it answers my question