# How to fix this small table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, titlesec, parts, titletoc

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titleclass{\part}{top}
\titleformat{\part}[display]
{\centering\normalfont}
{\itshape \partname~\thepart}{1.0em}
{\bfseries\MakeUppercase}
\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}

\dottedcontents{section}[5.0em]{}{3.5em}{0.75pc}

\begin{document}

\startcontents[parts]

\part{Part I}

\printcontents[parts]{}{0}{}

\chapter{Chapter I}
\section{Section I.1}

\chapter{Chapter II}
\section{Section II.1}

\chapter{Chapter III}
\section{Section III.1}

\stopcontents[parts]

\end{document}
```

Problem: add space between the bold Roman numerals and words (for chapters) in the table of contents.

Comment: Use `\titleclass{\part}{top}` command from the `titlesec` package for your first problem. `\part` by default enforces a page break in the `report` document class.

Comment: Also, refer to the `titletoc` package. `\printcontents` takes in *one* optional argument in *square* brackets and *three* mandatory arguments in *curly* brackets. What you have in your MWE is four curly brackets, and so it produces an error.

Comment: @Troy now the table of contents doesn't show up for me

Comment: For the first issue: You might use a `\vbox{...}` around the part and the `\printcontents`. This should prevent the pagebreak. With this approach you don't change the behavior of `\part` on other occasions.

Comment: The optional argument that you're passing to the `\printcontents` command is the `name`, which you need to pass to `\startcontents` and `\stopcontents` as well, but this is only used if you want to have multiple TOCs.. (Read the documentation if you want to know more). If you only have this one, then try this: `\printcontents{sections}{0}{}`

Comment: @Troy with an empty `[]` I get an error "No partial toc named ."

Comment: @RandyRanderson Why are you editing away your questions? Surely there is some value in keeping it around so that others in the future with the same question can refer to this and fix their problem.. Are you gonna delete this question once your last query has been solved? Anyway, have a look at this for your third question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33841/how-to-modify-the-space-between-the-numbers-and-text-of-sectioning-titles-in-the

Comment: The additional space should only be in the TOC, not in the actual headings?

Comment: @Troy the deleted questions were clearly answered in the documentation. last one is useful

Comment: @RandyRanderson As it stands then, your question is a possible duplicate of the link I attached above?

Comment: @Troy no, that solution doesn't work for my question. in particular i don't see how to use `\dottedcontents` to fix the chapter spacing

Comment: @RandyRanderson What exactly do you want to fix? In your question you mentioned the spacing in the section level, and here you mention the spacing in the chapter level.

Comment: @Troy i was using "section" too loosely. I meant both chapters and sections.

Comment: Try this for sections: `\dottedcontents{section}[0em]{}{3.2em}{1pc}`

Comment: What's left? And if you find answers to your questions, you really shouldn't edit your question but post an answer so that future visitors of this site can solve their own problems.

Comment: Compiling error is because of your `\dottedcontents{chapter}[1.0em]{}{3.0em}{}` change it to `\dottedcontents{chapter}[1.0em]{\bfseries}{3.0em}{0pc}`. This also solves the non-bold chapters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the chapter entries in your TOC bold and with adjustable space use `\dottedcontents{chapter}[1.0em]{\bfseries}{3.0em}{0pc}`.