# How to remove the space between the numbers and titles on the \tableofcontents?

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm using this preamble:

```
\documentclass[rascunho]{fei}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  output-decimal-marker={,},
  inter-unit-product=\ensuremath{{}\cdot{}},
}

\addbibresource{ref.bib}
```

but when i add the command

```
\tableofcontents
```

my summary becomes like this:[[image: 1]

but my goal is to have it look like this:

[[image: 2]

how can i delete this space in between the numbers and the titles?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to modify the space between the numbers and text of sectioning titles in the Table of Contents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33841/5764)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using the `fei` document class which, in turn, builds on the `memoir` class. The class file `fei.cls` contains the following instructions:

```
\renewcommand{\cftchapternumwidth}{4em}
\renewcommand{\cftsectionnumwidth}{4em}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsectionnumwidth}{4em}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsectionnumwidth}{4em}
\renewcommand{\cftparagraphnumwidth}{4em}
```

Observe that the same width -- `4em` -- is set aside for all five sectioning headers, from `\chapter` to `\paragraph`. If, instead, you want to set aside just enough space to typeset the number plus a minimalist amount of whitespace, you could run the following instructions in the preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\cftchapternumwidth}{1.0em}
\renewcommand{\cftsectionnumwidth}{1.75em}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsectionnumwidth}{2.5em}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsectionnumwidth}{3.25em}
\renewcommand{\cftparagraphnumwidth}{4em} % no change

\defbibheading{bibliography}[\bibname]{%
  \clearpage
  \phantomsection
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bfseries REFER\^ENCIAS}
  \chapter*{REFER\^ENCIAS} 
  \urlstyle{same}}
```

The `\defbibheading` instruction above modifies the one given in the file `fei.cls` to insert no whitespace before `REFER\^ENCIAS` is inserted in the toc file.

Comment: oh my, i was certain that i had commented here, it worked perfectly, thank you very much for that help, now it looks exactly like the way i wanted to. You saved my life !!
Thanks again !