# scrbook: spacing between section number and title in toc

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, tocloft, scrbook

I would like to increasing the space between section number and title in the toc. 
I tried to solve the problem using `\setlength\cftsectionnumwidth{ }` but this does not work with the class scrbook.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\cftsetindents{section}{0pt}{15pt}
\cftsetrmarg{2cm}
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1}
\section{Section 2}
\section{Section 3}
\section{Section 4}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spacing - How to modify the space between the numbers and text of sectioning titles in the table of contents? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33841/how-to-modify-the-space-between-the-numbers-and-text-of-sectioning-titles-in-the)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `tocloft` (not recommended with a KOMA-Script class) the number width for the entries in TOC is set by the third argument of `\cftindents`. Assumnig the number width should be `50pt`

```
\cftindents{section}{0pt}{50pt}
```

But you will get the same result using

```
\setlength\cftsecindent{0pt}
\setlength\cftsecnumwidth{50pt}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\cftsetindents{section}{0pt}{50pt}% <- changed
\cftsetrmarg{2cm}
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addchap*{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1}
\section{Section 2}
\section{Section 3}
\section{Section 4}
\end{document}
```

---

Suggestion **without `tocloft`**:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocindent=0pt,
  tocnumwidth=50pt,
]{section}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  toclinefill=\hfill
]{section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{2cm}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addchap*{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1}
\section{Section 2}
\section{Section 3}
\section{Section 4}
\end{document}
```

---

Because of a comment below: The headings of TOC, LOF and LOT are chapters by default (with a book class). So if you want to modify the font of the TOC title and the skip below the TOC title, you can use eg.

```
\BeforeTOCHead[toc]{%
  \addtokomafont{chapter}{\normalsize}
  \RedeclareSectionCommand[afterskip=1sp]{chapter}%
}
```

If you remove the optional argument, then the the titles of the lists (LOF and LOT) will change in the same way.

Comment: Is there also a command for \cfttoctitlefont and \cftaftertoctitleskip without tocloft?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: the "without tocloft" part of this answer does not seem to change anything in the LOF. How would it have to be modified?

Comment: @lucidbrot Use `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry` oder `\DeclareTOCStyleEntries`, eg. `\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[linefill=\hfill]{tocline}{figure,table}`