# Differents sizes for \section titles

Tags: titles, appendices, size

I would like to add an appendix to my report. In order to do that, I add the appendix package which "rename" \section to Appendix A, B, etc ... But I want to make it smaller while keeping the others \section of the documents as the same size as before. Do you know how to do that ? Thanks in advance, Romain.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\begin{document}
\section{Title of the section}
\begin{appendices}
\section{Title of the appendix A}
\section{Title of the appendix B}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

When I try the following command, I have a problem with the table of content.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
%\usepackage[title]{appendix} % No longer needed
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\appendix{\par
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \setcounter{subsection}{0}%
  \gdef\thesection{Appendix \@Alph\c@section}
  \renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
    {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
    {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
    {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}% from \Large
  \renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
    {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
    {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}% from \large
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Title of the section}
\appendix % Added
%\begin{appendices} % No longer needed
\section{Title of the appendix A}
\section{Title of the appendix B}
%\end{appendices} % No longer needed
\end{document}
```

Comment: For the toc problem see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33841/15925

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
%\usepackage[title]{appendix} % No longer needed
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\appendix{\par
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \setcounter{subsection}{0}%
  \gdef\thesection{Appendix \@Alph\c@section}
  \renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
    {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
    {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
    {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}% from \Large
  \renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
    {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
    {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}% from \large
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{Title of the section}
\appendix % Added
%\begin{appendices} % No longer needed
\section{Title of the appendix A}
\section{Title of the appendix B}
%\end{appendices} % No longer needed
\end{document}
```

Note that I don't use `appendix` package but the result in your MWE is the same. If you have other reasons beside having `Appendix [...]` in each section and subsection let me know.

Comment: Yes, It seems to work thanks. However, It seems to generate a problem with the table of content (\tableofcontent). Do you know how to change that ?

Comment: Please add an edit to your question with the new mwe and the description of the problem. (Don't modify what you already wrote, just add the new issue)

Comment: Ok no problem. Done.