# scrreprt: unnumbered chapters, numbering within sections - how to remove period?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, numbering, koma-script, scrreprt

Using KOMA-Script's report class `scrreprt`, I'd like to have chapters without any numbering, and have normal (Arabic numerals) numbering within each section (in text and in ToC), like so:

```
Chapter about A
    1 Thing a
        1.1 Subthing aa

Chapter about B
    1 Thing b
        1.1 Subthing bb

Chapter about C
    1 Thing c
        1.1 Subthing cc
```

Currently, this is the output I get, and the question is **how to remove the extra period**:

```
Chapter about A
    .1 Thing a
        .1.1 Subthing aa 

Chapter about B
    .1 Thing b
        .1.1 Subthing bb

Chapter about C
    .1 Thing c
        .1.1 Subthing cc
```

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter about A}
\section{Thing a}
\subsection{Subthing aa}

\chapter{Chapter about B}
\section{Thing b}
\subsection{Subthing bb}

\chapter{Chapter about C}
\section{Thing c}
\subsection{Subthing cc}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default section numbering is

```
\newcommand*{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
```

If `\thechapter` is empty, the dot is still there. So you would have to redefine `\thesection` too:

```
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
```

This will automatically also change `\thesubsection` … `\thesubparagraph`, because they all depend directly or indirectly on `\thesection`.

But what about figures, tables, equations? They all have similar definitions like the section. So you would also need to redefine `\thefigure`, `\thetable` and `\theequation` similar to `\thesection`. But then you will have several sections, subsection … subparagraphs and several figures, tables and equations with the same number. So I would recommend not just to redefine `\thesection`, `\thetable`, `\thefigure` and `\theequation` but make their counters independent from the `chapter` counter. You can use `\counterwithout` to do so, e.g.,

```
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}
```

to make the `section` counter independent from the `chapter` counter. This will also redefine `\thesection` like I've shown with the explicit redefinition above.

But this is not enough. In your example the chapter titles still start with an indent. This is the space between the (not existing) chapter number and the chapter title text. So you have to remove this space too. You can do this redefining `\chapterformat`:

```
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{}% No number and no space
```

You should do the same for the running heads (used if you are using `\pagestyle{headings}`):

```
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{}
```

All together I would recommend:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% Not needed with LaTeX from 2018-04-01

% \usepackage{chngcntr}% Only needed with old LaTeX.

\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{}% No number no space
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{}% No number no space
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}
% This also results in \renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\subparagraphnumdepth}% number every sectioning level from \part till \subparagraph (not recommended to do so)
\setcounter{tocdepth}{\subparagraphtocdepth}% add every sectioning level from \part till \subparagraph to the ToC (not recommended to do so)

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter about A}
\section{Thing a}
\subsection{Subthing aa}

\chapter{Chapter about B}
\section{Thing b}
\subsection{Subthing bb}

\chapter{Chapter about C}
\section{Thing c}
\subsection{Subthing cc}

\end{document}
```

If `\counterwithout` results in an error, you should either update your LaTeX or activate the commented `\usepackage{chngcntr}`.

Maybe you'd also want to change the spacing in the table of contents. But this would be [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33841/9057).

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you very much for taking the time to formulate this detailed answer, and for thinking ahead so many steps!