# Tableofcontents

Tags: table-of-contents

[image: Please help me. How to solve it?]

Hello. Please help me.

When I make table of contents in latex maked following problems. I use text numbering in section like this

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{Тест \arabic{section}}
\ection{} .
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! When posting on this site, you should always write down your code instead of showing a picture of it. This way, others can copy and paste it to try it and work out the problems. To solve your problem, it is hard to be really helpful without having a compilable code producing the problem. Could you add a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)?

Comment: Another question with relevant information: [How to modify the space between the numbers and text of sectioning titles in the table of contents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33841)