# Spacing issues in list of equations

Tags: equations

I've used this code to create a list of equations into my document of type **report**

```latex
\begin{document}

% config for the list of equations
\newcommand{\listequationsname}{Liste des Equations}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par}

\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} 
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} 
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\listoftables
\clearpage
\listofalgorithms
\clearpage
\listofmyequations
```

the problem is that the spacing is not okey
[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  This question might give some help: [How to modify the space between the numbers and text of sectioning titles in the table of contents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33841)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know how the OP is using it, because the OP failed to provide a minimum working example.  However, it was clear that `tocloft` is being used.  And in this case, the key is something like `\setlength{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{1in}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}

% config for the list of equations
\newcommand{\listequationsname}{Liste des Equations}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par}
\setlength{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{1in}

\begin{document}

\listofmyequations

\begin{equation}
y = mx + b
\end{equation}
\myequations{The linear equation}

\begin{equation}
E = mc^2
\end{equation}
\myequations{The energy equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this solution is exactly what I wanted.