# Poorly spaced TOC from Lyx (chapter numbers and title merge)

Tags: table-of-contents, lyx

**Context:** I am using Lyx with the KOMA-Script-Book class to generate a book with a table of contents. I am not using any special hacks, just the vanilla configuration via the Lyx GUI. My preamble has only one line of code `\setcounter{chapter}{-1}`.

**Problem:** The contents page shows the chapter numbers too close to the chapter titles. See image below to best illustrate the problem.

Any suggestions for how to fix?

[image]

Comment: The numbers in a TOC are placed in a box of a set width (so the text following the number aligns). You need to increase this setting. Though I have no idea as to how one does that in LyX.

Comment: try `\KOMAoptions{toc=flat}`. Or read the KOMA documentation about more 
options to adapt the table of contents.

Comment: thanks @UlrikeFischer that worked. if you'd like to make it an answer I'll mark it as done. (I added toc=flat as an option in the lyx UI)

Comment: It's highly unlikely that Lyx has anything to do with this.  The spacing of chapter and section numbers is almost always defined by the document class.  See [How to modify the space between the numbers and text of sectioning titles in the table of contents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33841)

Comment: Thanks @barbarabeeton - I was surprised as by default I'd expect tex / latex to layout such that it wasn't squished, especially as there is enough space available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `\KOMAoptions{toc=flat}`. Or read the KOMA documentation about more options to adapt the table of contents.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about Lyx (what is it?) but for the traditional classes (book, report, article) the tocloft package lets you do what you want.

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\addtolength{\cftchapnumwidth}{2em} % increase space for chapter numbers
```

Comment: thanks Peter - useful reply. I found the solution by Ulrike was simpler for Lyx. Lyx is a GUI for editing documents typeset by latex which aims to be zero-code (but clearly keeps failing. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LyX

Comment: as Penelope uses the KOMA classes, tocloft is probably not the best solution.