# Table caption title's second line does not align with first line

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, captions, titles

I am trying to adjust the table caption to appear in the List of Tables index page. Below is the problem I am facing. I have the issue where the second line of table caption not aligning with first line.

This only happens when the table it of two lines. Initially, even the first line of table 10.10 was displaying as **10.10C**. To fix this i added,

\begin{table}[htttp]

\centering

\caption{\hspace{0.18cm}C

...
...
}

But this could fix only the first line, the second line is still slightly unadjusted. I tried \hspace, \hfill, \textwidth but no success.

Any other solutions which could in this scenario?

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Can you create a small document with just enough stuff to reproduce the problem? Manually adding space is definitely not the way to go here, but it won't be possible for people to suggest better options without code.

Comment: In particular, please reveal which document class you employ and which packages (if any) you employ to affect the appearance of the table of contents and list of tables.

Comment: Don't add formatting commands like `\hspace{…}` to your caption. If your class does not provide another interface: Use a package like [`caption`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) to configure the formatting of the caption inside the `table` environment and a package like [`tocbasic`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocbasic), [`tocloft`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) or [similar](https://ctan.org/topic/toc-etc) to configure the entries in the list of tables. There are already a lot of questions about how to do this.

Comment: Similar or even duplicate: [How to modify the space between the numbers and text of sectioning titles in the table of contents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33841/277964), but you'd have to replace `subsection` by `table` resp. `subsec` by `tab`. See the manuals of the used packages for more information.