# No space between section heading and numbering

Tags: spacing, sectioning

I'd like my section headings to be displayed directly after the section numbering with no space in between.
This should be the case regardless of the number.
Something like this:

```
1. A section heading
2. Another section heading
...
1526. Yet another section
```

Currently I'm using `titlesec` with

```
\titleformat{\section}{\large\bfseries}{\makebox[1pt][l]{\thesection}}{12pt}{}
```

but this causes heading and large numbers to overlap.

Comment: I've some doubts this being typographycally sound: at least a normal space should follow the dot.

Comment: @egreg You're right, a normal space is required

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: I also found [Customize spacing between section number and its caption?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11569/customize-spacing-between-section-number-and-its-caption)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update:** there's an easier solution with `titlesec`: the `\thetitle` command is
respectively `\thesection`, `\thesubsection`, etc. The default value in standard classes is:

```
\titlelabel{\thetitle\quad}
```

which means that after the number, an space of `1em` is inserted; to change this behaviour is enough then to redefine `\thetitle` to add a dot and then a space:

```
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\ }
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}% just for the example

\titlelabel{\thetitle.\ }

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section}
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\subsubsection{Test Subsubection}
\paragraph{Test Paragraph}
\subparagraph{Test Subparagraph}

\section*{Test Section}
\subsection*{Test Subsection}
\subsubsection*{Test Subsubection}
\paragraph*{Test Paragraph}
\subparagraph*{Test Subparagraph}

\end{document}
```

[image]

One possibility using the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package affecting `\section` through `\subparagraph`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}% just for the example

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection.}{0em}{~#1}
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0em}{#1}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection.}{0em}{~#1}
\titleformat{name=\subsection,numberless}
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{}{0em}{#1}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection.}{0em}{~#1}
\titleformat{name=\subsubsection,numberless}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{}{0em}{#1}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph.}{0em}{~#1}
\titleformat{name=\paragraph,numberless}[runin]
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{}{0em}{#1}
\titleformat{\subparagraph}[runin]
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubparagraph.}{0em}{~#1}
\titleformat{name=\subparagraph,numberless}[runin]
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{}{0em}{#1}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section}
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\subsubsection{Test Subsubection}
\paragraph{Test Paragraph}
\subparagraph{Test Subparagraph}

\end{document}
```

I can't upload images; will do it later.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work perfectly for me. I could use some explanation, though.

Comment: @Jakub of course; I am really busy right now, but in a few hours I'll add some explanatory comments.

Comment: @Jakub I found an even simpler solution; I updated my answer showing this simpler possibility.

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way, without any package, is to redefine `\@seccntformat`, which usually adds `\quad` after the section number:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\csname the#1\endcsname.\ }
\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{10}

\begin{document}
\section{Test Section}
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\subsubsection{Test Subsubection}
\paragraph{Test Paragraph}
\subparagraph{Test Subparagraph}
\section*{Test Section}
\subsection*{Test Subsection}
\subsubsection*{Test Subsubection}
\paragraph*{Test Paragraph}
\subparagraph*{Test Subparagraph}
\end{document}
```

The `\` command after the dot ensures that the space is not affected by the space factor; so the space doesn't grow if `\nonfrenchspacing`, the default setting in LaTeX, is in force: it's a normal interword space in the current font.

I've used `geometry` only to add the frame; the setting of `secnumdepth` is only for demonstration purposes, I don't recommend going too deep in the numbering of sectional units.

[image]