# Defining the space between section number and section title

Tags: spacing, sectioning

I am trying to define the spacing between the section name and section title in latex to get something like this . How can I do it?

[image]

Also how can I define the margin and all at the first page to get the margin of the title of the paper from the top followed by the authors like this.

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Perhaps `\usepackage{cvpr}`? I found a copy of cvpr.sty at http://www.pamitc.org/cvpr13/author_guidelines.php and it produces the style illustrated in your figure.

Comment: Special case of [sectioning - Customize spacing between section number and its caption? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11569/customize-spacing-between-section-number-and-its-caption).

Answer (score 13):

The distance is defined (in the standard classes and so those that load them) by `\@seccntformat`, whose usual definition is

```
\newcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}
```

So the space is a quad (1em) in the current font. If you want a normal interword space, put the following magic in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter % access to internal commands
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname\ }
\makeatother
```