# Handling margins and indent in itemize

Tags: spacing, lists, indentation, itemize, enumitem

I have looked around the site for a while and haven't found a specific answer about this particular problem:

I am typing up a paper and was asked to separate different sections with headings. I would like to use `itemize` to do so, but have had trouble with formatting. I want the text to align with the rest of the document, so I found I should use the `enumitem` package so that I can adjust `leftmargin`. Here is an example of what I have now:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum, enumitem}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0cm]
\item[I.] First Section

\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[2]

\item[II.] Second Section

\quad \quad \lipsum[3]

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

This is the exact format I want except I noticed that the paragraphs are no longer indented. I tried using `\indent`, but to no avail. For now, I am using `\quad \quad`, which is neither the same as an indent nor good markup, I'm sure.

Do any of you know a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm providing an alternative view on your input that is more in line with the semantics of a document with sectional division:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,sectsty,indentfirst}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{sectsty,indentfirst}

\sectionfont{\normalsize\normalfont}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\leavevmode\llap{\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\section{First Section}

\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Second Section}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Here are some references to the elements changed inside the MWE preamble:

- [Defining the space between section number and section title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/139022/5764)
- [Roman numerals for sections and subsections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26882/5764)
- [Is it possible to change text color for all headings?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68376/5764)
- [No indent in the first paragraph in a section?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39227/5764)

Comment: Thank you very much Werner! I don't know why I was trying to make it harder on myself than it had to be. I appreciate how complete your answer was - I will be following those links to learn more about that code you added to the preamble. It seems I have just started to scratch the surface!