# Remove space between section number and title

Tags: spacing

I've defined a custom section title as follows:

```
\renewcommand\thesection{Lecture \arabic{section} --}
```

This leaves an unwanted gap between "Lecture n -" and the title of the lecture.
For example, `\section{Linear combinations and subspaces}` gives the following output:
[image: Image of problem]
I would like there to be a normal text space between the numbering and title. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Crosslink: special case of [sectioning - Customize spacing between section number and its caption? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11569/customize-spacing-between-section-number-and-its-caption).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better to redefine the way a section counter is formatted (via `\@seccntformat`) for this purpose than redefining the entire counter representation. Why? Redefining the counter representation would filter down to `\label`s as well, and therefore `\ref`erences also.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{Lecture~\csname the#1\endcsname{} -- }
\makeatother

\newcommand{\lecture}{\section}% For consistency sake...

\begin{document}

See Lecture~\ref{lec:linear-combinations-and-subspaces}.

\lecture{Linear combinations and subspaces}
\label{lec:linear-combinations-and-subspaces}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's a brilliant solution, I wasn't aware I could do it like that. Thank you so much!