# Distance Number and Subsection

Tags: subsection

Good morning, everyone.

I am recently attending Latex and would like to know how to customize the distance between the number and the voice within **\subsection**.
Thank you very much.

This is my code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Lorem}
\subsection{Ipsum}
\subsection{Dolor}
\end{document}
```

[image: subsection]

Comment: Pretty sure this is duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11569/customize-spacing-between-section-number-and-its-caption but the answer is quite dense.

Comment: Too difficult for me! Anyway, I'll read everything well tonight. Thank you.